# Select QUERY inner joining Fields to get text values instead of ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like this...

```
Tbl1
User           OriginalValue   NewValue            FieldName
MikeS          11              12                  Dept
BobL           140             141                 Position
JohnS          11 South St     13 South St         Address
JenB           9               12                  AmountPaid
BillyS         133             132                 Seller
```

Here's what the table looks like. In case a user edited a record, I saved the original values and new values. Now here's what I'm trying to do. I need to be able to display text instead of ID's (numbers). With the exception of (in this example) AmountPaid, and Address - all values are in tblDefinition that looks like this.....

```
tblDefinition
ID              Name             Field
9               SomeValue        SomeX
10              SomeValue        SomeX
11              Accounting       Dept
12              Finance          Dept
132             Microsoft        Seller
133             Apple            Seller
140             Manager          Position
141             Entry            Position
```

So i wanted to include a bunch of data to illustrate what tblDefinition looks like. I'm trying to somehow be able to use Field and ID from tbl1 and Join it with the tblDefinition to get the text values. I need to use the FieldName because some of the values that might appear in Original and New Values such as Fieldname = AmountPaid have corresponding values in the tblDefinition, but I actually need to display the value as it is - in this case 9, and 12.

```
Select OriginalValue,  Newvalue, Field
from tblDefinitions
LEFT JOIN tblDefinitions on (tbl2.OriginalValue = tblDefinitions.ID and tbl2.NewValue=tblDefinitions.ID)
```

Here's what I've been trying but this is not going anywhere - I'm really having a hard time figuring out if I can do something like that in one query, or if I need to do multiple unions for each field that has a corresponding text value in the tblDefinitions or what

EDIT. Maybe something like....

```
Select t2.Name as OriginalValue from 
tbl1 t1
inner join tblDefinitions t2 on t2.ID = t1.originalvalue
where field in ('Dept', 'Position', 'Seller')
```

Maybe as long as I only specify the fields to look for, it won't effect other values such as AMOUNT PAID in tbl1

Comment: is it not doable?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you should just join the definition table twice, once for the original name and once for the new name.

```
SELECT tbl2.OriginalValue
    ,tdo.name as OriginalName
    ,tbl2.Newvalue
    ,tdn.name as NewName
    ,tbl2.user
FROM tblBHH_HXfieldChanges tbl2
LEFT JOIN tblDefinitions tdo
        on tbl2.OriginalValue = tdo.ID
left join tblDefinitions tdn 
        on tbl2.NewValue = tdn.ID
```

Comment: I think I need to user the FieldNames ? don't you think, for AmountPaid - those values are not supposed to be coming from tblDefinitions but rather it's supposed to stay as is (9) but if i run it against the tblDefinitions it will pull a value. That's my issue